# Is it idiomatic Python to use an abstract class for event handler callbacks?

Tags: python, events, callback

I am building an event dispatcher framework that decodes messages and calls back into user code.  My C++ background suggests that I write:

```
class Handler:
    def onFoo(self):
        pass
    def onBar(self):
        pass

class Dispatcher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.handler = Handler()

    def run():
        while True:
            msg = decode_message() # magic
            if msg == 'foo':
                handler.onFoo()
            if msg == 'bar':
                handler.onBar()
```

Then the framework user would write something like:

```
class MyHandler(Handler):
    def onFoo(self):
        do_something()

dispatcher = Dispatcher()
myHandler = MyHandler()
dispatcher.handler = myHandler
dispatcher.run()
```

But I can also imagine putting `onFoo()` and `onBar()` as methods of `Dispatcher` and letting the user replace them with other methods.  Then the user's code would look like:

```
def onFoo():
    do_something()

dispatcher = Dispatcher()
dispatcher.onFoo = onFoo
```

I could also make `Dispatcher.onFoo` a list of callables, so the user could attach more than one handler like in C#.

What is the most Pythonic way to do it?

Comment: Why are you building an event dispatcher framework? Plenty exist already.

Comment: I'm not building anything general purpose - I probably made the project sound bigger than it really is. It's just a messaging layer that decodes Protocol Buffers messages and calls the appropriate functions.

Comment: To expand a little more: I want to avoid relying too heavily on third party libraries as I have already encountered some pain integrating them in my company's large proprietary code base.  I want to keep the possibility of yanking out the libraries and replacing them with Invented Here code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't say that there's anything particularly *wrong* about doing it the first way, especially if you want to allow `Dispatcher` objects to be customized in an organized way at runtime (i.e. by passing different kinds of `Handler` objects to them), if your `Handler`s need to interact with and maintain complex state.

But you don't really gain anything by defining a base `Handler` class this way; a class could still subclass `Handler` without overriding any methods, because this isn't an abstract base class -- it's just a regular base class. So if there are some sensible default behaviors, I would suggest building them in to `Handler`. Otherwise, your users don't gain anything from `Handler` at all -- they might as well just define their own `Handler` class. Though if you just want to provide a no-op placeholder, then this set-up is fine.

In any case, I would personally prefer the first approach to the second that you suggest; I'm not certain that either is more "pythonic," but the first seems like a cleaner approach to me, since it keeps `Handler` and `Dispatcher` logic separate. (It avoids situations like the one you see in `threading.Thread` where you can only safely override *some* methods -- I've always found that a bit jarring.)

I feel I should point out, though, that if you really want a bonafide abstract base class, you should write one! As of 2.6, Python provides support for flexible [abstract base classes](http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html) with lots of nice functionality. For example, you can define an abstract method with the `abstractmethod` decorator, which ensures that it *must* be overridden by the subclass; but you can also define regular methods that don't have to be overridden. If you're seeking a Pythonic version of the c++ idiom, this is probably the best way to go -- it's not the same thing, of course, but it comes closer than what you have now.

Comment: I don't care about abstract base classes that much.  I want to provide a default no-op behavior so users don't have to handle every event if they don't want to.

Comment: @japreiss, ah, I see -- that makes sense. I wasn't thinking about it that way. I'm not sure _pythonicity_ comes into it then; for what it's worth, I would prefer the first version, but I don't see that either is more pythonic than the other.

Comment: Is there a better way to do it?  It looks like Twisted uses class inheritance for event handlers.  I haven't done much event-driven stuff in Python so I'm not sure if this is the 'normal' way.

Comment: @japreiss, I think it really depends. I've worked with PyGTK before, and have used both approaches. If the handler needs to maintain its own state -- which was often the case for me -- then a class makes a lot of sense, and that's the approach I tend to prefer. But sometimes you just want to define a simple function -- even a `lambda` -- in which case the class-based approach may be overkill.

Comment: Yeah, that was pretty much my thought too.  6 of one, half dozen of the other.  There is a fair amount of state to manage, so that makes me feel better about using classes.  This is one of Python's disadvantages IMO: it supports so many coding styles that it's hard to choose sometimes.